# Make text heavier using pdfrender for article thanks field and pagenumbers

Tags: article, rendering

I want to make text heavier with `pdfrender` package for printing on laser printer. But field `thanks` and pagenumbers does not havier then other text. Is this a bug or imperfection of package or I should to change code from `article.cls`?

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\title{Rendering}
\author{A. U. Thor\thanks{Def}}
\pdfrender{TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=1pt}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing: you're talking about a "thanks" field but in your code there is none, you're talking about missing page numbers but in your screenshot they are there. Could you please explain a bit better what you are asking, with code showing actually what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Superuser27 I try to make the text of pdf much bolder for printing. As you can see from screenshot, `pdfrender` package do this, but only for text, but not for thanks and pagenumber

Comment: Ohh sorry now I understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the author of the `pdfrender` package himself:

> It's a feature. Package `pdfrender` redefines `\normalcolor` to reset the "normal" behavior. For example, there is some emphasized text via `\pdfrender` and a page break occurs. Then the header and footer should have normal rendering.

But you can still change that:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\title{Rendering}
\author{A. U. Thor\thanks{Def}}
\makeatletter
\let\normalrender\PdfRender@NormalColorHook  
\let\PdfRender@NormalColorHook\@empty         %redefine to do nothing
\newcommand*{\textnormalrender}[1]{           %so it doesn't switch back to \normalcolor
  \begingroup\normalrender#1\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\pdfrender{TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=1pt}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```